# How to extract an array of column names ordered by parameter index from an PostgreSQL conditions string?

Tags: javascript, regex, postgresql

Say I have this string which represents PostgreSQL query `WHERE` conditions:

```
(a > $3 OR a < $4 OR (b <= $1 AND b >= $4)) OR (c = $1 AND (c != $2 OR c <> $3)) OR (d @> $5 AND (d <@ $6 OR c && $6)) OR e || $7
```

How may I extract an array of column names (a, b, c) that would be ordered by parameter indexes ($1, $2, $3) that are compared to the column names?

The result should be:

```
[ // comments display parameter indexes by which the array is ordered
  b, //$1 $4
  c, //$1 $2 $3 $6
  a, //$3 $4
  d, //$5 $6
  e  //$7
]
```

Note that if the first parameter ($1) is compared to multiple times, then the first item in the array would simply be a column name that was parsed first.

This is an array of known operators:

```
[ '<=', '>=', '!=', '<>', '@>', '<@', '&&', '||', '<', '>', '=' ]
```

Comment: Are col names ordered by first occurring parameter they compare to? and have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution should cover your case

Regex : `/((\w) (?:<=|>=|!=|<>|@>|<@|&&|\|\||<|>|=) (\$\d))/g`
This groups the **operators** and column **parameters** which can then be aggregated

```js
var str= "(a > $3 OR a < $4 OR (b <= $1 AND b >= $4)) OR (c = $1 AND (c != $2 OR c <> $3)) OR (d @> $5 AND (d <@ $6 OR c && $6)) OR e || $7"

var regex = /((\w) (?:<=|>=|!=|<>|@>|<@|&&|\|\||<|>|=) (\$\d))/g;

var match;
var result = {};
while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  var column = match [2];
  var parameter = match[3];
  result[column] || (result[column] = [])
  result[column].push(parameter)
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Yep, exactly! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, one caveat: it requires correct spacing. Maybe you should add a quantifier  to the spaces  e.g.: `/((\w) *(?:<=|>=|!=|<>|@>|<@|&&|\|\||<|>|=) *(\$\d))/g`